# Поменять коллекцию в datagrid wpf mvvm

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Доброго времени суток всем. Такой вопрос мне нужно поменять коллекцию данных в datagrid

Есть datagrid

```
<DataGrid Style="{DynamicResource DataGridStyle}"
                                                      ItemsSource="{Binding DataDistrictPoint, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                                      SelectedItem="{Binding SelecetedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                                      AutoGenerateColumns="True"
                                                      Width="418"
                                                      Height="200"
                                                      Margin="40,10,0,0"
                                                      VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                                      CanUserAddRows="False">
                                                <DataGrid.InputBindings>
                                                    <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftDoubleClick"
                                                                  Command="{Binding GoDistrictPageCommand , Mode=OneTime}"
                                                                  CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=UsersDataGrid, Path=SelectedItem}" />
                                                </DataGrid.InputBindings>
                                                <DataGrid.Columns>
                                                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="№"
                                                                        Binding="{Binding IdDisctrictPoint,Mode=OneWay}"
                                                                        MinWidth="80"
                                                                        Width="20" />
                                                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding DisctrictPointX, Mode=OneWay}"
                                                                        MinWidth="120"
                                                                        Width="*">
                                                       
                                                    </DataGridTextColumn>
                                                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding DisctrictPointY,Mode=OneWay}"
                                                                        MinWidth="120"
                                                                        Width="*">
                                                       
                                                    </DataGridTextColumn>
                                                    <DataGridTextColumn 
                                                                        Binding="{Binding DisctrictPointZ,Mode=OneWay}"
                                                                        MinWidth="120"
                                                                        Width="*">
                                                      
                                                    </DataGridTextColumn>
                                                </DataGrid.Columns>
                                            </DataGrid>
```

В ViewModel коллекция:

```
 private ObservableCollection<DistrictPoint> _dataDistrictPoint = new();
        public ObservableCollection<DistrictPoint> DataDistrictPoint
        {
            get
            {
                using (GeocomplexContext db = new())
                {
                    var data = db.DistrictPoints.Where(r => r.IdDistrict == PassedParameter).ToList();

                    foreach (var item in data)
                    {
                        _dataDistrictPoint.Add(new DistrictPoint
                        {
                            IdDisctrictPoint = item.IdDisctrictPoint,
                            DisctrictPointX = item.DisctrictPointX,
                            DisctrictPointY = item.DisctrictPointY,
                            DisctrictPointZ = item.DisctrictPointZ

                        });
                    }

                    return _dataDistrictPoint;
                }
            }
            set
            {
                _dataDistrictPoint = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("DataDistrictPoint");
            }
        }
```

Модель
DistrictPoint:

```
  public partial class DistrictPoint
    {
        public int IdDisctrictPoint { get; set; }
        public int IdDistrict { get; set; }
        public double? DisctrictPointX { get; set; }
        public double? DisctrictPointY { get; set; }
        public double? DisctrictPointZ { get; set; }

        public virtual District IdDistrictNavigation { get; set; } = null!;
    }
```

Как заменить на другую коллекцию с другими данными в datagrid допустим когда пользователь из combobox выбрал другое значение, не создавая новый datagrid ?

------------Дополнение---------------

Коллекцию на которую мне нужно поменять
Коллекция:

```
ObservableCollection<AngularMeasure> _angularMeasureCoordinat;
        public ObservableCollection<AngularMeasure> AngularMeasureCoordinat { get => _angularMeasureCoordinat; set => Set(ref _angularMeasureCoordinat, value); }
```

Класс AngularMeasure:

```
 internal class AngularMeasure
    {
        private int _id;
        /// <summary>
        /// ID
        /// </summary>
        public int ID
        {
            get { return _id; }
            set { _id = value; }
        }



        private string _longitude;
        /// <summary>
        /// Долгота
        /// </summary>
        public string Longitude
        {
            get { return _longitude; }
            set { _longitude = value; }
        }

        private string _width;
        /// <summary>
        /// Долгота
        /// </summary>
        public string Width
        {
            get { return _width; }
            set { _width = value; }
        }

        private double? _pointZ;
        /// <summary>
        /// Координат Z
        /// </summary>
        public double? PointZ
        {
            get { return _pointZ; }
            set { _pointZ = value; }

        }
    }
```

Как в datagrid поменять коллекцию с DataDistrictPoint на AngularMeasureCoordinat

Comment: Привяжите `ComboBox.SelectedItem`, в сеттере вызовите `OnPropertyChanged` для свойства с коллекцией. Что-либо конкретное написать сложно, так как вы не показали комбобокс и его привязки. Кстати `DataDistrictPoint` - get-only свойство должно быть, сеттер не имеет никакого смысла, так как геттер никак не использует сохраненные данные в коллекции, а заполняет коллекцию заново из БД, кстати вы забываете ее очищать перед заполнением, либо создавать новую. Дополнительно обращение в базу синхронное, морозит UI при работе.

Comment: @aepot Так вот же создается  новая `private ObservableCollection<DistrictPoint> _dataDistrictPoint = new();`

Comment: Однократно, а вам надо пересоздать, ведь так?

Comment: @aepot Добавил правки в вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Вам не нужно менять коллекцию. Вам нужно в VM перезаписывать элементы коллекции с помощью методов, которые вызывают событие CollectionChanged(обновление интерфейса)
DataDistrictPoint.Remove и DataDistrictPoint.Add.

Вот модель:

```
 public class DistrictPoint
    {
        public int IdDisctrictPoint { get; set; }
        public int IdDistrict { get; set; }
        public double? DisctrictPointX { get; set; }
        public double? DisctrictPointY { get; set; }
        public double? DisctrictPointZ { get; set; }

    }
```

Вот ViewModel

```
public class MyVM 
    {
        public MyVM()
        {
            Case1 = new List<DistrictPoint>
            {
                new DistrictPoint()
                {
                    DisctrictPointX = 1,
                    DisctrictPointY = 2,
                    DisctrictPointZ = 3,
                    IdDisctrictPoint = 4,
                    IdDistrict = 5
                },
                new DistrictPoint()
                {
                    DisctrictPointX = 6,
                    DisctrictPointY = 7,
                    DisctrictPointZ = 8,
                    IdDisctrictPoint = 9,
                    IdDistrict = 10
                }
            };

            Case2 = new List<DistrictPoint>
            {
                new DistrictPoint()
                {
                    DisctrictPointX = 10,
                    DisctrictPointY = 20,
                    DisctrictPointZ = 30,
                    IdDisctrictPoint = 40,
                    IdDistrict = 50
                },
                new DistrictPoint()
                {
                    DisctrictPointX = 60,
                    DisctrictPointY = 70,
                    DisctrictPointZ = 80,
                    IdDisctrictPoint = 90,
                    IdDistrict = 100
                }
            };

            ListForCombobox = new List<int> { 1, 2 };
        }

        private int selectedCombobox;

        public int SelectedCombobox
        {
            get => selectedCombobox;
            set
            {
                selectedCombobox = value;
                switch (value)
                {
                    case 1:
                        int count = DataDistrictPoint.Count;
                        for (int i = count; i != 0; i--)
                        {
                            DataDistrictPoint.Remove(DataDistrictPoint[i - 1]);
                        }
                        foreach (var item in Case1)
                        {
                            DataDistrictPoint.Add(item);
                        }

                        break;
                    case 2:
                        count = DataDistrictPoint.Count;
                        for (int i = count; i != 0; i--)
                        {
                            DataDistrictPoint.Remove(DataDistrictPoint[i - 1]);
                        }
                        foreach (var item in Case2)
                        {
                            DataDistrictPoint.Add(item);
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<DistrictPoint> DataDistrictPoint { get; set; } = new(); // коллекция для DataGrid

        public List<DistrictPoint> Case1 { get; set; } //коллекция, полученная из БД при combobox == 1

        public List<DistrictPoint> Case2 { get; set; } //коллекция, полученная из БД при combobox == 2

        public List<int> ListForCombobox { get; set; } // коллекция отображаемая в Combobox
    }
```

Вот view:

```
<DockPanel>
        <ComboBox
            DockPanel.Dock="Top"
            ItemsSource="{Binding ListForCombobox}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCombobox}" />

        <DataGrid
            VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="False"
            Margin="5,10"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            CanUserAddRows="False"
            ColumnWidth="*"
            GridLinesVisibility="Vertical"
            HeadersVisibility="Column"
            IsReadOnly="True"
            ItemsSource="{Binding DataDistrictPoint}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn
                    Width="20"
                    MinWidth="80"
                    Binding="{Binding IdDisctrictPoint}"
                    Header="№" />
                <DataGridTextColumn
                    Width="*"
                    MinWidth="120"
                    Binding="{Binding DisctrictPointX}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn
                    Width="*"
                    MinWidth="120"
                    Binding="{Binding DisctrictPointY}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn
                    Width="*"
                    MinWidth="120"
                    Binding="{Binding DisctrictPointZ}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </DockPanel>
```

Алгоритмы перебора коллекций можно и допилить... я сделал на скорую руку.

Comment: Можете на примере показать, как это сделать?

Comment: Даже я не до конца понял этот ответ. Разве ObservableCollection не для этого служит?

Comment: Для чего "для этого"?) Чтобы ObservableCollection уведомляла view нужно одно из трёх: вызывать метод Add, метод Remove, либо через индекс заменять в ней элемент. Просто присваивание ей новой коллекции не вызовет событие CollectionChanged и view не отобразит изменений

Comment: Я обновил ответ с указанием примера. Критику принимаю)